# How can I tell that this Leverage browser caching is on?

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-expires

I am trying to set the expiring date on the images/js/css ext.. on my site because i see in a tool that I am using [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) that it will help performance:

```
The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:

http://somesite.com/images/chat/footer_btn_chat_on.png (expiration not specified)
http://somesite.com/images/footer.jpg (expiration not specified)
http://somesite.localhost/inc/cache/all.js (expiration not specified)
```

So I added this to the htaccess and refreshed the page and still the (expiration not specified):

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 60 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 60 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 60 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 60 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 60 days"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 360 days"
</IfModule>
```

Do I need to turn anything on or is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: reset your browser's cache and try again. Also check if you have mod_expires loaded: `LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so` in httpd.conf.